# Read from argv[0]

Tags: c, argv

How can I read from `argv[0]`? I'm using NetBeans. Everytime, I have to type in stdin. When I use `argv`, then the program executes without my input.

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char *text;
  int textLen,repNum;

  text = stream2string(stdin,&textLen);
  //....text = argv[0] doesnt work :(
```

**UPDATE:**

When I compile and run, I have to Type an Example String! The string is always the same: `ABAABAABBBA`. So I will take the first argument instead of stdin. But `argv[1]` doesn't work either.

Here's `stream2string()`:

```
char *stream2string (FILE *fptr, int *n)
{
  static char *s;

  *n = 0;
  ALLOC(s,char,2);
  s[*n] = getc(fptr);

  while(s[*n]!=EOF && s[*n]!='\0' && s[*n]!='\n') {
   REALLOC(s,char,++*n+2);
  s[*n] = getc(fptr);
   }
  s[*n] = '\0';
  return(s);
} /* stream2string() */
```

I think setting `textLen` is also important.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is or what you are trying to accomplish, can you clarify with a full example program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What is the value of argc when you have an argument?
argv[0] should hold the executable's name; your first argument is supposed to be in argv[1].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

argv[0] is the name of your executable; I don't think you want to read from that!  Rather, I think you want to open argv[1] (the filename given as the first argument to your program on the commandline) and read *that*:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char *text;
  int textLen,repNum;
  FILE *theinput;

  if (argc < 2) {
    /* no argument */
    /* give error message and exit */
    fprintf(stderr, "Must pass an argument!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  theinput = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  if (!theinput) {
    /* Argument is non-existing file */
    /* give error message and exit */
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't read %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

  text = stream2string(theinput, &textLen);

  fclose(theinput);
```

etc. (Of course you can and should provide more detailed and helpful error messages, etc, etc, but I'm trying to focus on the key points that you appeared to be missing).

**Edit**: ah well, focus seems out of fashion, judging from the comments, so I just edited
to provide minimally acceptable error messages.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value of fopen before you attempt to read from theinput!

Comment: OK, added some error checking, was trying to keep it simple (as I see that nobody else's giving any code, I guess that once again this proves how trying to actually be helpful on SO is a mistake;-).

Comment: use argc first to see if there is at lest 1 argument

Comment: It isn't a mistake and I commend you (and upvoted you) because you provided a clear answer to an unclear question, taking the time to attempt to reasonably interpret the problem. I made my comment because the OP is an apparent newbie and setting good examples for error checking is important, IMHO, especially since I see so many experienced programmers fail to do so.

Comment: @Robert, good points, though abundant inline error-checks and messages can end up being confusing to beginners (they hide the mainline logic) -- that's the big plus of exceptions, btw, getting error handling "out of the way" to make the mainline stand out more starkly, simply and clearly. Anyway, I gave up on focus and clarity given that @hiena also seems to think that checking in minute detail to provide just the right message is more important than having the OP understand what's going on!-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use argv[1] instead to read the first argument.
argv[0] returns the name of the executable that was called (or the name of the link to the executable on Unix/Linux systems).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you haven't set the program arguments for when it is run in the IDE. This is a NetBeans issue - nothing to do with C.